# Keras does not utilize 100% cpu

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I build sequential model with keras and tensorflow backend.
As you seen on picture, model uses all cores but none of them 100%.
I would like to know, how to make keras+tf utilize every core by 100%.

I tried to build tensorflow from scratch and reinstall, but it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Which network do you train? If there are many fully connected or conv layer, I think the CPU usage would be 100%.

Comment: @pgplus1628  There is sequential model with 3 layers + batch normalization. It trains pretty slowly, so I think it should be 100% usage.

Comment: is there any possibility that performance is bounded on the data loading

Comment: @pgplus1628 No, i checked I/O activity and it is around 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out, my model was too simple to utilize 100% cpu. After adding more neurons to the network, cpu utilization increased to almost 100%.

I dont know, why keras don't use availible cpu power to compute simple models faster.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tensorflow-gpu?
Then most of the computation will run on the gpu and the cpu load will not be 100%

Comment: I am not using GPU.